# Como usar no @Html.CheckBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
@{
   var st = //(minha lógica q retorna bool);
}
@Html.CheckBox("MeuNome",st,new { id = "MeuID", value = "MeuValor" })
```

Não consigo usar a variável `st` no segundo parâmetro do método... Já tentei `st, @st, @{st;}` e nada. Como posso usar a variável de forma a alterar menos possível o código?

O código acima está dentro de um `@using(@Html.BeginForm()){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alterando menos possível é só você jogar a } para baixo... Isso atende?

E bem vinda ao StackOverFlow :)

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigada!